# CSS/HTML: a tag with a span inside, span margin creating white space on hover underline

Tags: html, css, whitespace

I have a link with a span inside, I want to place a margin on the span so it is distanced from the link title, however, when I use the :hover for underline, a white space is created where there is no underline. I want the underline to be the full width of the link element. How do I do this? Thank you.

http://jsfiddle.net/EY387/

HTML

```
<div>
    <a href="#" class="link-1">
        <span class="span-1">1</span>
        Hello
    </a>    
</div
```

CSS

```
.link-1 {
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.link-1:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.span-1 {
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Are you able to change your HTML? Is it possible to wrap the text "Hello" in a span?

Comment: Do you *want* the underline to take the full width of the element, or do you want it to stop at the 'title' text, or something else entirely?

Comment: I tried using a span before but it did not change anything http://jsfiddle.net/EY387/1 And I want the underline to be cover the full width of the link element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove margin to span. margin space not taking underline on hover.

For space use `&nbsp;`. As in this following markup:

```
<div>
    <a href="#" class="link-1">
        <span class="span-1">1&nbsp;</span>
        Hello
    </a>    
</div>
```

Css:

```
.link-1 {
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.link-1:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.span-1 {
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zPq4G/)

Comment: thank you, this does work. But using &nbsp; does not let me control the size exactly, and it forces me to rely on the font and font-size used. I will have to experiment and see the results.

Answer (score 1):

Though it may not be exactly what you're looking for, why not try a border?

HTML

```
<div>
    <a href="#" class="link-1">
        <span class="span-1">1</span>
        Hello
    </a>    
</div>
```

CSS

```
.link-1 {
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.link-1:hover {
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}
 .span-1 {
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VBm2B/1/)
As @DavidThomas explained, if having a border move elements underneath is a problem, the use of a box-shadow could be easily swapped for the border-bottom.
Illustrated [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VBm2B/4/)

Comment: Plus the span is really filled with an icon that is text based and accessed using css (i.e. Symbolset)

Comment: Apologies, let me fix the answer. Edit inbound.

Comment: Yep; this seems to be the only way this can be effected (even if it's not quite the same visually). I *would* suggest that you add a transparent border-bottom to the non-hovered state, otherwise content below the link will jump (visually uncomfortable) when it's hovered/unhovered.

Comment: @DavidThomas, the same result could easily be achieved with an inset box-shadow. My only hesitation was compatibility issues with some browsers. You know, he shall not be named? *cough* IE *cough*

Comment: Not really, unless I've missed some new developments in `box-shadow` implementation (this could be true, though); a `box-shadow` (inset or otherwise) is visible against *all* borders of the element, rather than just one. (Or, this was true the last time I played around with `box-shadow`, which was some time ago...) [Although...](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/VBm2B/5/)

Comment: I just edited the answer yet again and included a demo using box-shadow rather than border-bottom.

Comment: I saw; I honestly hadn't (ever) considered trying to do it that way.